# npm starting and testing correctly

Tags: angularjs, terminal, npm

I am learning how to test angular applications based on [this tutorial from Google.](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). I have node properly running in the terminal v4.4.0 and I have not been able to find a direct answer.

I have the application running when I change to the specific directory, followed by npm start.

How does a user test the app other than closing the terminal completely, opening a new terminal window and running:

```
npm test
```

To resume back to the application running, I close the terminal, open a new terminal and start the node again

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Well duh. I opened a tab in terminal when I has npm started, then ran npm test in the new tab.

Is there a less demanding way to do this by the way on using less resources of the computer?

Thank you.